# Can I declare a stage agent to override the root agent in my Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cicd

I'm writing a Jenkins pipeline for an `npm`-based project.

Most of my stages in the pipeline only need the `node` runtime to execute (`npm run lint`, `npm run test`, `npm run build`...).

But I have a later stage where I want to run my automated Cypress tests. This one needs to run in the [`cypress/included`](https://hub.docker.com/r/cypress/included) container.

I thought I could:

1. declare a root docker agent (using the `node:18` Docker image),
2. not declare any agent in stages simply requiring `node` (therefore implicitly inherit from the root agent),
3. explicitly declare a docker agent using the `cypress/included` image in the Cypress stage (therefore overriding the root agent).

But when doing so, everything works fine until the Cypress stage, where I have a weird *docker login error*.

What I'd like to do:

```
pipeline {
  // default root agent
  agent {
    docker {
      label "shared"
      reuseNode true
      image 'node:18' 
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Verify') {
      parallel {
        stage('test') {
          steps {
            sh "npm run test"
          }
        }
        stage('lint') {
          steps {
            sh "npm run lint"
          }
        }
        ...
      }
    }
    stage('Build & Deploy') {
      steps {
        sh "npm build"
        sh "aws s3 sync ..."
      }
    }
    stage('Cypress') {
      // override default agent for this stage only, but reuse same workspace
      agent {
        docker {
          label "shared"
          reuseNode true
          image 'cypress/included' 
        }
      }
      steps {
        sh "cypress run ..."
      }
   }
}
```

Question: is it supposed to work?

If not, why? This is not tackled in the documentation.

Note: Not declaring any root docker agent and explicitly declaring the right docker agent in each stage of the pipeline works but it's much less elegant (violates the *don't repeat yourself* principle, as I keep (re)defining the same docker agent many times). Moreover with this solution, Jenkins keeps `docker pull`-ing the node image at each stage, while with the alternate solution it simply reuses the agent with the installed container.

Comment: I have never worked with docker. But I have worked around declarative and scripted pipeline. Did you try using the `node` command? I am not sure it is the solution but exploring this might help you because you can use it in a declarative pipeline to change the agent you are executing on.